# Get users rank from couchDB

Tags: view, couchdb

I'm trying to get the users rank from a couchDB database. The issue I'm having is I have multiple users and multiple games. I want to be able to pass 2 keys

1. The app id
2. The users score

I would like to then see how many records have the same app id and a lower score then the one I passed. This would return the users current rank. This is how my document structure is

```
{
   "_id": "c68d16e1d8ba65accf97230dfbf7c2cb",
   "_rev": "114-2aea3eef75c73e1079ed9c8d945723e1",
   "credits": 2125,
   "appName": "someApp"
}
```

I've tried setting views up but the multiple keys are really confusing me. This is what I've tried but hasn't worked

**VIEW**

```
"getrank": {
   "map": "function(doc) { emit([doc.appName, doc.credits],{credits:doc.credits}) }"
}
```

**URL CALLS I'VE TRIED**

```
/players/_design/views/_view/getrank?key=["someApp","2000"]&startkey=["credits",2000]

/players/_design/views/_view/getrank?key=someApp"&startkey=["credits",2000]
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, emitting a value here is unnecessary as you will get the "credits" data back in the key of your results anyway. This will spare both storage and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to then see how many records have the same app id and a lower score then the one I passed.

If I understand your question correctly your view looks good. Maybe instead of emitting an object you can just do `doc.credits` or simply null and query it with `&include_docs`..

Any way what you need to do is to query over a range. `startkey` and `endkey` should work.

`_view/getrank?startkey=["someApp",minima]&endkey=["someapp",maxima]`

what this query does is give you records for someapp between minima and maxima. Now we need to build upon this.

> lower score then the one I passed.

first we need to query it in a descending manner. The only interesting thing here is that the order of keys will reverse:-

`_view/getrank?startkey=["someApp",maxima]&endkey=["someapp",minima]&descending=true`

now suppose you want everything lower that 9000. Here is the final query that will do the trick

`_view/getrank?startkey=["someApp",9000]&endkey=["someapp",{}]`

This gives you all the scores for some app less than 9000.

I have not actually run these queries but this should give you something to work with.

If you need all the records over a range you need range queries.

Range queries are done with startkey and endkey.

They are reversed when descending=true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed comment. I was able to get it working just seconds after reading this comment!

Comment: A side question I have...I have a view that pulls all the users scores to show a leaderboard list. Is it possible to pull just the users rank as well as all the users scores at the same time?

Comment: If you have diff views then you need to make 2 requests